# siblings() not working when using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Please take a look at the following two fiddles. One has jquery mobile and the other does not (jquery only). The jquery only version finds the siblings, but the jqm version does not! What am I doing wrong?!

```
$("#UCMRegSel").change(function() {
    $(this).siblings("select").toggleClass("toggle");
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).siblings('select').each(function() {
        if (self != this)
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

JQM version: https://jsfiddle.net/dpatel20/1e2Ltr04/

Jquery only version: https://jsfiddle.net/dpatel20/teLx8Ly1/

Comment: JQM creates extra containers ti the `select`. So siblings function wont work.

Comment: One more thing in class of select you have added . with the name of class name class=".selGroups"

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e2Ltr04/3/) . You'll need to change the code to access the select when you have JQM.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan - Thanks Rejith, that works! If you put it as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile creates extra containers ti the select. So siblings function wont work.

Use the following instead.

```
$("#UCMRegSel").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.ui-select')
    .siblings(".ui-select").toggleClass("toggle");
  $(this).closest('.ui-select')
    .siblings(".ui-select")
    .each(function() {
        var select = $(this).find('select').eq(0);
        if (self != select)
        console.log(select.attr('id'));
  });
});
```